# Gaussian Matrix Model - Large N Expansion Physics with Mathematica

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, quantum-computing

Update: Attempted 2nd time by replica method

I'm trying to implement basic large N expansion in Mathematica.

I'm trying to understand what this means on the fly as well.

The model I am trying to implement is the basic "Matrix Model" with some interaction term(s).

I am following 2.1 in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.11574.pdf) article.

I am also referencing t[his too](https://math.unice.fr/%7Epatras/CargeseConference/ACQFT09_GKrishnaswami.pdf)

2nd Attempt (by replica method?)

```
(*define the size of the matrix and the number of replicas*)
 n = 4; \
\[ScriptCapitalN] = 10;

(*define the potential parameter*)
a = 1;

(*define the potential function*)
V[M_, a_] := -a Tr[M . M]/(2 n) + Log[Det[M]]

(*initialize the partition function*)
Z = 0;

(*loop over all possible configurations of the matrices*)
Do[(*define a random n by n matrix*)
 M = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}];
 (*compute the contribution to the partition function*)
 Z += Exp[-\[ScriptCapitalN]*V[M, a]], {i, 1, \[ScriptCapitalN]^2}]
Clear[\[ScriptCapitalN]]
(*take the average of the partition function*)
Z /= \[ScriptCapitalN]^2;

(*take the logarithm and perform a Taylor expansion*)
LogZ = Series[Log[Z], {\[ScriptCapitalN], 0, 1}];

(*compute the free energy*)
FreeEnergy = 
  Limit[LogZ/\[ScriptCapitalN], \[ScriptCapitalN] -> Infinity];
Clear[a]
(*compute the mean eigenvalue*)
m = -D[FreeEnergy, a];

(*compute the variance of the eigenvalues*)
sigma2 = -D[FreeEnergy, {a, 2}]/n;
Z
```

1st Attempt

```
(*Matrix dimension*)
\[ScriptCapitalN] = 4;

g0 = 0.1;
g1 = 0.1;
g2 = 0.1;
g3 = 0.1;

(*Generated random matrix*)
X = Table[RandomReal[], {\[ScriptCapitalN]}, {\[ScriptCapitalN]}];

(*Trace generic invariants*)
V0 = Tr[X . Transpose[X]];
V1 = Tr[X . Transpose[X]]^2;
V2 = Tr[X . Transpose[X]] . Tr[X . Transpose[X]];
V3 = Tr[X . Transpose[X]]^3;

(*Action S*)
S = \[ScriptCapitalN]/2 *V0 + g3 *V3;

(*Path integral measure*)
dX = Table["dX"[i][j], {i, \[ScriptCapitalN]}, {j, \[ScriptCapitalN]}];
pathIntMeasure = 
  Product[dX[[i, j]], {i, 1, \[ScriptCapitalN]}, {j, 
    1, \[ScriptCapitalN]}];
DX = Flatten[dX];

(*Partition function*)
Z = Integrate[Exp[-S] , DX];
```

Comment: `S0`, `S1`, `S2` are not defined as functions in your code so `S0[Y0]` doesn't evaluate to anything. You should also include the definition of `Y`.

Comment: @MarcoB I have now reduced this to thinking about the leading order.  X is defined such that S0  is defined as functions. S0[Y0] should now evaluate.  How does one code first and second order?

Comment: Your `S[Y_]` definition calls `Y[t]`, but your model calculation uses `S[Y[x,y,t]]` which is incompatible. How is your code supposed to know to supply the `t`-values into the third argument of `Y`? I think you need to learn about [anonymous functions](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/26-pure-anonymous-functions.html) and how functions can be passed to other functions.

Comment: @Roman I have now edited the code.  Will look into anonymous functions in a bit. Was also sort of just trying to first write something basic for now mostly to understand large N expansion.

Comment: Are you simply trying to take $\mathcal{N}\to\infty$? Or is the dimension of your matrices supposed to increase as well?

Comment: @Roman $\mathcal{N}\to\infty$ as well. Also, I have now attached a reference on this that I am trying to follow.  I am still tinkering with this too.

Comment: @Roman I added another attempt by replica method